# Algorithm: How to find sub set of a set when new elements are added?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, subset, dynamic-programming

I have a subset algorithm that finds all the subset of a given set. The thing with the original set is that it is a growing set and if elements are added to it, I need to re-compute the subset of it again.

Is there a way that I can optimize the subset algorithm that can recompute the subset from the last computed point, instead of computing whole thing again and again.

```
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSetsOf<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            if (!source.Any())
                return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1);

            var element = source.Take(1);

            var haveNots = SubSetsOf(source.Skip(1));
            var haves = haveNots.Select(set => element.Concat(set));

            return haves.Concat(haveNots);
        }

        private static bool Valid(IEnumerable<int> set)
        {
            bool flag = false;

            foreach (var element in set)
            {
                var f = element > 0;
                if (f == flag)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                flag = f;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: The only new subsets you obtain when adding an element are those that contain it, so if you already know the collection C of all subsets prior to adding element e, you add "S union e" to that collection for each subset S in C.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you only need to apply the same algorithm to each previously generated element to the extra set (only the growing part)

Ex :

if the generated subsets are `s1, s2, ... , sn`

and your set grow from `a1a2a3` to `a1a2a3a4a5`

you need to iterate over subsets to the extra added set :

```
for set x in subsets do :
    generate(x)
        generate(x + a4)
        generate(x + a5)
```

**Btw** I see you added dynamic-programming tag, but I don't think this is a dp problem since dp is used mostly for problem that require to maximize/minimize/counting subsets, but not generating subsets them selfs.